# $request->hasFile() returns false when uploading

Tags: php, laravel

I can't seem to get my app to upload a file when submitting a request in my Laravel 5.8 application. No matter what type of file I upload, `hasFile()` always returns `false`.

#### Form

```
<form action="{{ route('items.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group py-50">
        <input type="file" name="featured_img" value="featured_img" id="featured_img">
    </div>                    
      
    <div class="form-group">    
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </div>                                    
</form>
```

#### Controller

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //Check if image has been uploaded
    if($request->hasFile('featured_img')){
        return "True!"; 
    } else {
        return "False!";
    }  
}
```

#### dd() Output

```
array:7 [▼
  "_token" => "sREFSO8bs0rWil05AESVrwEl37XtKOJAF2nCkTNR"
  "status" => "published"
  "featured_img" => "example.jpg"
  "submit" => "Upload Image"
]
```

- `enctype="multipart/form-data"` has been included in my form.
- I have tested multiple files which are around 50-80 KB in size
- I am running another Laravel app in the same environment without any issues. I also tested uploading the same images to that app without any problems. This leads me to believe this has nothing to do with misconfiguration of `php.ini`
- `dd($request->all());` returns a string name for `"featured_img"` instead of file object

### UPDATE

While Making changes to my view I did not realize I had two form actions in place with the same route. Stupid me. Thank you for everyone that helped me troubleshoot.

Comment: and what does `$request->file('featured_img')` returns?

Comment: dd($request->file('featured_img')); returns NULL

Comment: Can you check what you are getting in your laravel.log file?

Comment: can you try this one request()->has('featured_img');

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu no errors in log

Comment: @SafakCiplak returns true

Comment: @EricS. your dd output seems like a completely different form. Where is the status field?

Comment: @nakov sorry, I forgot to delete the status field from the dd output. I have a few other form fields in the form but they are not relevant to the issue. I also have no validation in place on any of the form fields so they are just left blank when I try submitting the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested in one of my installation with
in web.php

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
Route::get('test', function(){
    return view('test');
});
Route::post('test', function(Request $request){
    dd($request->hasFile('test'));
})->name('test');
```

in test.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ route('test') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
   <div class="form-group py-50">
     <input type="file" name="test" id="featured_img">
   </div>                    

    <div class="form-group">    
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </div>

  </form>
```

`$request->hasFile('test')` returns true, please check with this code in your controller or route file and let me know, if you are getting any issue.

Also

*You should use @stack to add script to your blade and not @section*

**Update**

According to your updated view page code, you have two form in your view posting to same route check that and first form is not closed and second is open.

Comment: Removing the value attribute did not make any difference. hasFile() still returns false

Comment: @EricS. Can you dd ( $request->all() ) and tell me what you are getting now?

Comment: Same as before
`array:7 [▼
  "_token" => "sREFSO8bs0rWil05AESVrwEl37XtKOJAF2nCkTNR"
  "status" => "published"
  "featured_img" => "example.jpg"
  "submit" => "Upload Image"
]
`

Comment: @EricS. I have updated my answer please check it and let me know the result.

Comment: Your test does work in my environment when I created a new test blade and added your code to my web.php file

Comment: when I implement your code exactly my dd returns true. However, if I copy the code into my own view and update my controller to only contain the dd, I return false. There must be something else wrong with either my controller or blade.

Comment: @EricS. In stead of controller if you will use route file(web.php) and your view, what you are getting?

Comment: I have updated my post to include my entire index.blade.php file. If I delete all contents and only include the form my controller returns TRUE. There must be something wrong with my view.

Comment: @EricS. You have started first form and written second form inside the first, there is the error.

Answer (score 2):

check try some case:

1. check max file size upload in php.ini
2. check exist *enctype="multipart/form-data"* in  tag or not.
3. check method in  tag (must use POST method), and route in Web.php must have post route